# InvalidParameterValueException when trying to register a new QuickSight user

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-quicksight

I'm trying to register a new QuickSight user with the following command:

```
aws quicksight register-user --identity-type IAM --email email@email.com --aws-account-id ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID} --user-role READER --namespace default
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the RegisterUser operation: Invalid resource identifiers provided. Please check the documentation.
```

The message returned is not very clear about what exactly is wrong or what parameter is invalid. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `--session-name` and `--iam-arn` and it worked. Apparently both are required when using `--identity-type IAM`.

Comment: what value you provided for --session-name, I can't get it to work.

Comment: it's been a while now, so I don't remember exactly. But I'd try to used as is, without any value. If a value is required then I'd try to find what session means in this context (something I don't remember either). Not sure my comment is helpful, but this is the best I can do now.

Comment: You can use any string value. If you're using Terraform to deploy your resources, you can see from the following example that the session_name can be any value:
`resource "aws_quicksight_user" "example" {
  session_name  = "an-author"
  email         = "author@example.com"
  namespace     = "foo"
  identity_type = "IAM"
  iam_arn       = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Example"
  user_role     = "AUTHOR"
}`
See the documentation https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/quicksight_user for more info